# Aptana rails error on Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, aptana

I successfully installed Ruby , rails , git following instructions form this **[link](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04)**. I then tried to install aptana rails. After extarcting the package and running I get two problems , 
1 - "Showing Startup Page"

```
An internal error has occurred.
No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
```

I tried to solve this issuse using stackoverflow but none of the solutions work for me.

2- Some gems wont install from Auto-install like sqlite3-ruby. I tried to install this from terminal and it worked, but Aptana rails is not identifying this update. Same goes for another gem "ruby-debug-ide" and "ruby-debug-base"

Answer (score 0):

I really went down a rabbit hole on this one, but the problem was ultimately solved by installing version 3:

http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download.html

The rabbit hole included but was not limited to... openjdk vs. sun jdk (you have to remove open jdk completely ... I mean rm -Rf), and some kinda Derby database ... ANYWAY after much pain and suffering, I think it's a bug with Aptana where you can't change the jdbc url for Derby without the code.

Fixed in 3, apparently.